# Estimating server capacity for Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007, dell

I need a new server for exchange 2007, it'll have about 70 mailboxes. We prefer Dell (all our servers are Dell). How can I tell what kind of specs the server will require?

Comment: Suggestion: it's actually not a bad question, but the delivery is all wrong. Maybe you could edit your question in such a way that other people will find it useful too. Eg: "We're buying a new server on which to run Exchange 2007. What sort of specs would be appropriate for 50 mailboxes? Howabout if we expand to 100?"

Comment: As for the line about Dell... If you ring their sales team, I am sure they will be more than happy to advise you.

Comment: I have zero interest in running Exchange but I don't know why this question was downvoted to -2 when I got to it.  Now you're at -1. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a huge question without a simple answer... best advice is to [start reading](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/01/16/432222.aspx).

- [Planning Processor Configurations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998874.aspx)
- [Planning Memory Configurations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738124.aspx)
- [Planning Server Role Ratios](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738159.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

There is a Exchange 2007 Mailbox Server Role Storage Requirements Calculator spreadsheet available [here](http://msexchangeteam.com/files/12/attachments/entry438481.aspx). A blog post that explains how to use it and everything that is factored in is available [here](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/01/15/432207.aspx). The calculator uses all the recommendations outlined in the following articles:

Planning Storage Configurations - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124518.aspx
Planning Memory Configurations - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738124.aspx
Understanding Exchange Server 2007 I/O improvements from 64 bit - http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/09/08/428860.aspx

Also [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719.aspx) are the general system requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange 2007 needs some fairly heavy-duty hardware.  It also requires a 64-bit OS, so keep that in mind when selecting -- means if buying new you'll need a 64-bit version of Win 2008 Server.  I can't really speak to Dell hardware specifically, but for a single-server instance you'll want to hit it with at least 3-4 GB of RAM, and you'll probably want at least 2 way (probably 2 x 2 way or 1 x quad core) CPU at 3 GHz.  If you split up the store and the MTA/routing between boxes, you may be able to get away with a little less heavy-duty hardware.  HD space itself is fairly cheap, but you'll also want some kind of raid on the hard disks, preferably a hardware controller that's capable of raid 5 or raid 6 but you'll have to pay for it.  How much disk space depends on your mailboxes and what else you want the box to do (best answer: nothing).